# Checking a null refrence Firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a application where I get values from a reference. The issue I have now is at times the reference might not the present and if the refrence is not present, the user is just suppose to be in idle state. How ever, I do not know how to achieve this task as the particular refrence could be absent from the firebase.

Below is my code for checking the ref data

```
func refreshActiveTrip() -> Observable<Trip> {

        guard let trip = getCurrentTrip()  else {
            return Observable.error(RxError.noElements)
        }

        tripRef = Database.database().reference(forTransportChampionId: (getChampion()?.id)!, tripId: trip.id!)
        return Observable<Trip>.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in

            let disposable = Disposables.create {
                self.tripRef?.removeAllObservers()
            }

            self.tripRef?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    let trip = Trip(dictionary: data as NSDictionary)

                    self.saveCurrentTrip(trip)

                    if !disposable.isDisposed {
                        observer.onNext(trip)

                    }

                }
            })
            return disposable
        })

    }
```

`tripRef` could be null i.e it does not exsit, how can i check this and an idle value

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `exists()`

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("the_path").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        print("It exists!!")
    }else{
        print("Nope, doesn't exist!")
    }
})
```

[Firebase Doc Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDataSnapshot(im)exists)

Comment: the ref might not be present. not the snapshot

Comment: It's all the same. I think what you desire can be achieved with this method.